# python-escpos direct printing text

Tags: python, printing, thermal-printer

Hi I´m implementing a python script which should print some text in "realtime" on a little 58mm POS thermal printer. For this I´m using the python-escpos library. Everything runs fine but I find out that the printer starts to print after the script is finished. I cant understand that cause I want to send out diffenrent Epson.text("foobar") command during a loop. At the moment all the text-print-statements are printed after the complete loop (demo loop with some sleep(5)) is finished and I´m back at the command promt.

```
from escpos import *
from time import sleep

Epson = printer.File("/dev/usb/lp0")

while True:
 Epson.text("Hello World\n")
 sleep(5)
```

Comment: Can you please clarify the last statement?

Comment: I start the script with "sudo python script.py", then I can let it run for a while (example 30 seconds). The printer is doing nothing until i cancel the script. after canceling the printer starts and all the "hello world" printouts are printed

Comment: I found out that after doing a "Epson.close()" the printer starts to print - maybe the problem is that I´m using my thermal printer over the filesystem /dev/usb/lp0. For a workaround I would now open the file-connection to the printer in the while-loop and close it before the sleep(5).

Comment: Logically, this sort of printer is designed for printing tickets for customers. The ticket is always cut by the machine. I remarked that the printing begins when you have sent the Epson.cut() command

Answer (score 3):

I am currently maintaining python-escpos. (over at https://github.com/python-escpos/python-escpos)

With "File"-printer you have to call printer.flush() at the moment, otherwise the print buffer will not be sent.
I have opened an issue whether we should adapt the behaviour to that of the other printers.

Comment: Just an update: v2.1.2 of python-escpos does now automatically flush after every command.

Comment: I am using your scripts, adapted it to my EPSON TM-T88IV and V, changed both of the IDs to 0x04b8, 0x0e02 or 0x04b8, 0x0202, and I get an error message `TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'profile'` Do have an idea, what I can do ? Thanks for your help. Michael

Comment: You should probably create a new question for this. On first glance you probably have version 2.2 or something like this. Please make sure to check the right documentation for this version. The current version 3 is only available when you install preview-versions with pip (it is currently in alpha)